# Is iptables -p proto -m proto redundant?

Tags: iptables

I keep seeing "-p tcp -m tcp" all over the place, but it looks redundant.

Why the '-m' if the '-p' already matches the protocol?

Comment: IIRC it is a relatively new feature that iptables guesses which modules it has to load, in order to get certain functionality. TCP at least used to be a module that one could choose to load or not. So `-m tcp -p tcp` would be the most portable version of TCP rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems redundant at first place, because iptables already loads automatically some of the modules. With the `-p` you specify the protocol, where `-m` you create a match argument that will check for specific atributes of a TCP packet.

The documentation specifies that using the protocol(`-p`) is enough to load all match stuff. [Source](http://www.iptables.info/en/iptables-matches.html#TCPMATCHES) and quoting:

> ...These matches are loaded implicitly in a sense, just as the UDP and
>   ICMP matches are loaded implicitly. The other matches will be looked
>   over in the continuation of this section, after the TCP match section.

The use of this match will make sense to use when you have to filter multiple ports an you know that the `multiport` match does not load in the same fashion as the `tcp` one. Example:

```
# iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j ACCEPT
```

**tl;dr:** They are not redundant. It is just a shorthand on the same way you dont need to declare the default table(`-t filter`) to each rule.

Comment: Wasn't clear in first post. I had in mind the "classic" example of : `iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j DROP` (example which can be found all over the interwebz). In this case the -m tcp seems useless.

Comment: Yup. Pretty much the same if you add the table to this rule: `iptables -t filter -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j DROP`. When no table is specified, `filter` is the default. When using protocol TCP(`-p tcp`)  the match argument( `-m tcp`) can be implicit and it will be loaded by iptables

Comment: Well I had the feeling that `-m tcp` was useless in that case,  but wasn't sure.  I guess it first appeared somewhere and people kept using it.  Guess it's no harm though :)